# Enable GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler in production mode

Tags: gwt

In my GWT app, I have an error logger similar to http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2012/06/11/7-tips-for-exception-handling-in-gwt/

```java
    // Handle all exception errors
    GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler( new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
            Window.alert("caught it!");
                    }
            };
```

This code works perfectly in host mode but in production mode it is compiled out as described in the documents.  Is there a way to get this code into the production mode?

Documentation of GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the document:

> In Development Mode, the default handler prints a stack trace to the log window. In Production Mode, the default handler is null and thus exceptions are allowed to escape, which provides an opportunity to use a JavaScript debugger.

The *default* handler prints a stack trace in dev mode, and in prod mode the *default* handler is null, but if you wire in your own, it will be obeyed. If you want custom behavior for dev/prod mode, then add is `GWT.isProdMode()` check in your own custom handler.